# Access Control with Slim/PHP/Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim, access-control

I have a website based on Slim, Twig, PHP, SQL Server, which is running on an II.

I want to achieve some kind of GUI for an Administrator, where he can simply allow/disallow users to view specific parts (routes) of the website.

I can give a name to a route.

```
$Slim->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/route', function(){
    //
})->setName('route_name');
```

also i can get all names from the routes like this

```
$allRoutes = $this->router->getRoutes();
foreach ($allRoutes as $key => $value) {
    $target[$value->getPattern()] = [
        'methods'       => json_encode($value->getMethods()),
        'middlewares'   => json_encode($value->getMiddleware()),
        'pattern'       => $value->getPattern(), 
        'name'          => $value->getName(), 
    ];
}
```

and i can use the name in twig like this

```
<a href="{{ path_for('route_name') }}"> link </a>
```

I also can give a Slim route a middleware, which is called every call of the route.
My plan is to put the route names into a table, and specify which user is allowed to open which route.

Questions:

Is there any way to uniquely identify a route name? Because relying on a string (route name), which could easily be changed by the developer without getting notified to the website admin seems to be not the best idea.

Is there any way to somehow convince the twig template not to insert the -tag in the final html (which is served to the user), based on if the user is allowed (by the middleware) to open the route?

Comment: Changing a route name is not _that_ easy as it is used in multiple places in the code and your example (getting path using route name) shows that. So it doesn't seem to be a property meant to be changed regularly. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864730/slim-framework-how-to-make-an-access-control-list-with-slim#comment53649593_32138026) introduces an interesting project, and the question itself seems to be related to yours.

Comment: thank you, but the administrator needs to have a form like:  "Bob is allowed to see user data [ x ]", therefore it seems to be easier using a simple middleware/table construction

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to somewhat prevent name-mismatches between the route-names(strings) used in templates and in PHP/by the router.

> Use PHP constants for route names.

This will further enable auto-completion in IDEs and give you a central location for your route-names.

A misnamed\non-existant route(-constant) will trigger an exception for **both** - PHP code and the template - instead of only during rendering of the template. This is the main benefit of using this method.

An interface can be used to store all your route-name constants.
Then use these constants with twig's `constant` function.

PHP interface

```php
namespace Routing;

interface RouteName
{
    public const HOMEPAGE = 'home';
    // ... more routes
}
```

usage in PHP/Slim

```php
use Routing\RouteName;

$Slim->map(['GET'], '/', function(){
    // [..]
})->setName(RouteName::HOMEPAGE);
```

usage in Twig template

```
{{ path_for(constant('Routing\\RouteName::HOMEPAGE')) }}
```